# I need help fixing this VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am new In VBA. I dont know how to use it but I am trying. I am trying to create a code that say:

if tmin < t < tmax then put "Valid" in **the cell of the comment column** but if not then put "Invalid" only

if it is valid then check if the argument < 0.001
  if it is then put "Valid & LN" in cell

if the argument > 0.001 just put "Valid" only

if the argument > 10 put "Valid & 0"

Here is my try out that doesn't work

```
Option Explicit
Function VC(t As Double, argument As Double, tmax As Double, tmin As Double) As Double
Dim i As String
If tmin < t < tmax And argument < 0.001 Then
    i = "Valid & LN"
ElseIf argument > 10 Then
    i = "Valid & 0"
Else
    i = "invalid"
End If
End Function
```

Here is how it has to look like and the columns I am using:

Tmax & Tmin cells

[image]

Time, Argument and how the Comment cells have to look like

[image]

Comment: Firstly, your function should return a double and it does return anything. Secondly, in VBA a condition like `If tmin < t < tmax ...` returns a boolean (True of False). Do you like to say (in words) if `tmin` is less then `t` and `tmin` is less then `tmax`? If not, please explain what you need, from this point of view. Then, where that `i` which take values in your function to be used/"put"? Does your function return in a cell where you put the function name and its parameters? If yes, it must return a string. And the loop must be exited when a condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Three things: 1) `tmin < t < tmax` isn't valid in VBA. It's `(tmin < t) And (t < tmax)` 2) For a Function to return something, you need to assign to the function name, ie `VC = i` 3) retutn type should be `String` (or `Variant`)

Comment: In your first example you have 0.007849 which is **not** < 0.001. Therefore _Valid & LN_ is wrong according to your description, or did I get you wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is

```
Option Explicit

Function VC(t As Double, argument As Double, tmax As Double, tmin As Double) As String

    Dim i As String

    If tmin < t And t < tmax Then

        i = "Valid"

        If argument < 0.001 Then
            i = "Valid & LN"
        ElseIf argument > 10 Then
            i = "Valid & 0"
        End If

    Else
        i = "invalid"

    End If

    VC = i

End Function
```

Comment: @CatherineArmagost: `If tmin < t And t < tmax Then` Well this can be `If tmin < tmax Then`? Since `tmin` is less than `t` and `t` is less than `tmax`? I think you want `if t > tmin And t < tmax Then`